# How to resolve the compilation error in Java Class for Notepad++

Tags: java

I wrote a Hello world program in Java (JDK 13.1) in Notepad++ (7.8.1) and tried to run it on Windows Powershell. But it is showing me an error. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Are we suppose to guess the error ? Please edit your post and add code + error

Comment: Code and error samples would be very helpful...

Comment: You try to run a class file that has been compiled by Java 13 with Java 8.

Comment: And please don't post images of the error. Please copy the error out of Powershell and [edit] your question to include it there.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot (true, don't post pictures of text - post the text!) shows that your code was compiled in Java 13 (class file version 57) but is being run against Java 8 (supports up to v52).

This is likely a `PATH` problem whereby the `java` found by default is not the one you want. It is easy to prove by running `java --version`

You need to determine where your **Java 13** is located, test with

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk13\bin\java" --version
```

Ref:
Java version > class file version mappings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout

Comment: If you look at the [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58891364/1) of this question, not even the image was there. Just a "I have an error, please help ASAP".

Comment: That's really odd revision. @halfer made that change not OP, his quote is "Trim ASAP begging" but somehow the screencap appeared at the same time as if _he_ added it. I think SO is being a little buggy here?

Comment: There was a link to the image in the source code. New users can't post questions with images, so it was left out. Try to look at the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58891364/revisions), specifically, side-by-side markdown.